# Ошибка при при подключений к базе данных

Tags: java, mysql

Я только учусь писать код на джаве и столкнулся с такой ошибкой.
Пытаюсь создать приложение где через сервер добавляю,вывожу список людей серез Mysql. Но выдает эту ошибку

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Server.getStudents(Server.java:71)
        at ListStudentsPage.fillData(ListStudentsPage.java:35)
        at ListStudentsPage.<init>(ListStudentsPage.java:20)
        at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:27)
        at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Класс сервер

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Server{

private static Connection connection; 

public static void connect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bitlab", "root", "");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void disconnect(){
    try{
        connection.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    connect();


    try{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1990);
        System.out.println("Waiting for the client...");
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        PackageData pd = new PackageData();

        while((pd = (PackageData)inStream.readObject())!=null){
            if(pd.getOperationType().equals("ADD")){
                System.out.println(pd.getStudents().toString());
                addStudents(pd.getStudent());

            }else if(pd.getOperationType().equals("ADD")){

            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void addStudents(Students student){
    try{

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO students (id, name, surname, age) VALUES (\""+student.getName()+"\",\""+student.getSurname()+"\",\""+student.getAge()+"\")";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        statement.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Students> getStudents(){
    ArrayList<Students> student = new ArrayList<Students>();
    try{
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from students");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()){
            Long id = result.getLong("id");
            String name = result.getString("name");
            String surname = result.getString("surname");
            int age = result.getInt("age");

            student.add(new Students(id, name, surname, age));
        }
        statement.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return student;
}
}
```

Класс вывод студентов

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ListStudentsPage extends Container{
private JButton back;
private JTable table;
private String str []={"id", "name", "surname", "age"};

public ListStudentsPage(){
    setSize(700,500);
    setLayout(null);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setSize(500,300);
    table.setLocation(100,30);
    fillData();
    add(table);

    back = new JButton("Back");
    back.setSize(120,50);
    back.setLocation(290,350);
    add(back);
    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Main.frame.showMenu();
        }
    });

}
public void fillData(){
    ArrayList<Students> students = Server.getStudents();
    Object val[][] = new Object [students.size()][4];
    for(int i=0; i<students.size(); i++){
        val[i][0] = students.get(i).getId();
        val[i][1] = students.get(i).getName();
        val[i][2] = students.get(i).getSurname();
        val[i][3] = students.get(i).getAge();

    }

    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(val, str);
    table.setModel(model);
}
}
```

МейнФрейм

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
public Menu menu;
public AddStudentsPage add;
public ListStudentsPage list;

public MainFrame(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700,500);
    setTitle("Mini Project");
    setLayout(null);
    setResizable(false);

    menu = new Menu();
    menu.setLocation(0,0);
    add(menu);

    add = new AddStudentsPage();
    add.setLocation(0,0);
    add(add);

    list = new ListStudentsPage();
    list.setLocation(0,0);
    add(list);

    showMenu();
}
public void showMenu(){
    menu.setVisible(true);
    add.setVisible(false);
    list.setVisible(false);
}
public void showAddStudentsPage(){
    menu.setVisible(false);
    add.setVisible(true);
    list.setVisible(false);

}
public void showListStudentsPage(){
    menu.setVisible(false);
    add.setVisible(false);
    list.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Майн класс

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main{

    public static Socket socket;
    public static ObjectOutputStream outStream;
    public static MainFrame frame;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connectToServer();

        frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    //java -classpath mys....bin.jar; Server
    }

    public static void addStudent(Students st){

        PackageData pd = new PackageData();
        pd.setOperationType("ADD");
        pd.setStudent(st);

        try{
            outStream.writeObject(pd);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void connectToServer(){
        try{
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1990);
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я не вижу у вас подключения к базе. Вы сделали метод в `Server` ... `public static void main(String[] args) {
    connect();` но нигде его не вызываете.  Либо я что-то упустил

Comment: Если смотреть в дебаге и поставить брэйкпоинты на 12 и 28 строки (пройтись по методу `connect()`). Инициализация переменной _connection_ нормально проходит? Или уже там она _null_?

Comment: @Dred метод connect()  выше  main метода.      
public static void connect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bitlab", "root", "");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Comment: @МишаковАлександр он уже там нулл

Comment: @Ulan, так я же говорю о том, что вы ниоткуда не вызываете `Server.main()`

Comment: @Dred тут логика такая. Запускаю сервер через терминал соответсвенно 'Server.main()'. Он ждет подключения клиента. Через другой терминал подключаюсь как клиент 'Main.main()'. Или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: А вот тут интересно,как вы различаете где запуск Server,а где Main? Напишите терминальные команды.

Comment: @Dred Сперва запускаю Сервер `javac *.java` после  `java -classpath mysql...(драйвер mysql): Server.java` . В этом моменте сервер ждет подключения клиента, и через другой терминал я прописываю `javac *.java` после  `java -classpath mysql...(драйвер mysql): Main.java`. Тут терминал сервера отвечает что клиент успешно подключился, а терминал клиента выкидывает ошибку null

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на стектрейс. Снизу вверх. Источник в  Main.main(). И завершается все NPE, но класс Server метод getStudents(). Т.е, это не тот сервер, который запущен на терминале сервера. Это просто класс Server, который лежит на терминале клиента, у которого вы вызываете getStudents(), но он (этот класс Server) не делал подключение к базе и его connection == null.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець спасибо, очень помогли